# Possible to create a combo graph containing line and bar

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

just been tasked to create a bar chart with a line going across it for a dataset. I was wondering whether it is possible to have 2 or more line graphs going across a stacked bar graph?

I know there is a calculated aggregate that is available that can do average etc but it doesn't give me what i need, anyone know if there is a way possible to have both line and bar as a combo graph for a dataset.

thank you

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry i just cant follow the link you sent me. Where is the value listed bit I am stuck on

Comment: Cool sorted now, thanks